# Mono value is MonoOnErrorResume when i do a repository.save in spring boot, cosmosDb

Tags: spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb

I am using spring boot, cosmosDb integration.
I am successful in doing a findAll, findById etc. But unable to save into the repository.

The Mono which gets returned on the save method has the message "MonoOnErrorResume" when i call a toString() on it.

What could be possibly wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following will work. It will return the saved object wrapped in a Mono.

```java
 someRepo.save(someObject).subscribe();
```

You can do the following to print the streams signals and print the saved object retuned in the Mono.

```java
someRepo.save(someObject).log().subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thanks! Using subscribed helped !!